# Title is very small in search results

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, design, search

After the new left nav and responsive design changes were pushed, I noticed the title of questions in search results became very small: ([search example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Title+is+very+small+in+search+results))

> [image]

Can the title please be given a bigger font? In case it matters, Chrome 67 under Windows but pretty sure it's not browser specific.

Comment: Ah, I was busy asking the same thing. This happened on MSO when the left nav came out, and there was a question about it which had some helpful info. Unfortunately I can't find it at the moment :(

Comment: Oh, here we are... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369127/why-are-titles-so-small-when-searching/369153#369153

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not browser-specific at all; just a missing style. Should now be the same size as question links on tag filters, homepage, etc.